# Code organization with js-mvc framework

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, spine.js

I want to write a simple web application

it looks like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

+Friends     |      Here we have a few different pages
   John      |      1. Search form 
   Alex      |      2. When we click on search button we get results with paging
   Ashton    |      3. Other stuff which can change friends list menu etc  
             |   
+menu1       |
   subMenu1  |
   subMenu2  |
   subMenu3  |
   subMenu4  |
             |
             |
```

I think it must be a single page application that mean we using AJAX to communicate with server.

i havent a good experience with js mvc frameworks that's why can you please give me advice which framework choose and HOW TO DO RIGHT CODE ORGANIZATION?

At this moment i have experience with knockout and spine.

1. Knockout is not good choice for such UI type because of it's good for ui with heavy elements dependency. It's not our case.
2. Spine. Well spine i think  better choice then knockout. 
   But what is best code organization? May be any simular example?
   What parts of my app should be controller and what is model?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an MVC JS Framework, then I would give BackboneJS a try: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/.  Here is a great resource on how to build single page app using BackboneJS: http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-spas-jquerys-best-friends/

KnockoutJS is a MVVM Framework.  It's best used for model binding to UI elements. It can certainly be used for single page apps if you couple it with a router such as PathJS.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have experience with Spine I don't see a reason why you should switch to Backbone.
They are very similar so it probably won't make much of a difference.
For code organization I'd look at Spine's [examples](http://spinejs.com/pages/examples).

@t0nyh0 ps Backbone technically is an MV* Framework.